# Update Android icon notification in Statusbar regarding a process like download or export on Android 13

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, background-service

I have an export progress in my app and I want to update the icon according to my export progress in the Statusbar. I have implemented it like below and it works:

```
private fun buildExportNotification(): Notification {
    
    val icon = getExportIcon()

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat
        .Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .build()

    return notificationBuilder
}
```

When my export progress is updated then I update my notification like below:

```
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            exportProgressStateFlow.collect { progress ->
                exportProgress = progress.toInt()
                notification = buildExportNotification()
                with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                    notify(NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID, notification)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But the first icon is visible, after that when my export progress is updated, the icon inside the Statusbar will not update, and all the time during this progress the first icon is visible and it does not change. I need to update the icon during the export progress.

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the icon in the status bar gets updated properly when your export progress changes, you need to make sure that you are updating the notification's small icon whenever the progress changes. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
private var notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder? = null

private fun buildExportNotification(): Notification {
    val icon = getExportIcon()

    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat
        .Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)

    return notificationBuilder!!.build()
}

// Update notification when export progress changes
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        exportProgressStateFlow.collect { progress ->
            exportProgress = progress.toInt()
            notificationBuilder?.setSmallIcon(getExportIcon()) // Update small icon
            val updatedNotification = notificationBuilder?.build()
            if (updatedNotification != null) {
                notification = updatedNotification
                with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(applicationContext)) {
                    notify(NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID, notification)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this modified code, I've added a notificationBuilder property to hold the instance of the notification builder. Then, whenever the export progress changes, I update the small icon of the notification builder using setSmallIcon() method. Finally, I rebuild the notification with the updated small icon and notify the notification manager to display the updated notification.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion, I did this like your suggestion but nothing changed.

Comment: I am getting the new ID for my drawable during the export progress. My getExportIcon() was fired and then notified my notification with the same ID (NOTIFICATION_FOREGROUND_ID), but the icon was not updated.

Comment: While the code is structured to update the notification icon correctly, some consideration
1- Ensure that the notification channel is correctly configured, and its properties, such as importance level and visibility, do not interfere with icon updates

2-Verify that NotificationManagerCompat is correctly handling the updated notification and that there are no conflicts with other notifications or system behaviors.

3-Ensure that the app has the necessary permissions to update notifications, such as android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT or android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY.

Comment: Ensure that the getExportIcon() function is returning the correct drawable resource ID. You can log the returned drawable resource ID to verify if it's the expected value.

Also, check if the notification is being successfully updated after calling setSmallIcon() and rebuilding it. Log messages or breakpoints can help you confirm whether the notification is being updated with the new icon.

Comment: This answer (and the associated comments) looks like it was copy-pasted from ChatGPT